# Unwind 3 arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, unwind

MongoDB collection data with multiple arrays:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61aa6bf1742b00f59b894eb7"),
    "first": ["abc", "def", "ghi"], 
    "last": ["rst", "uvw", "xyz"],
    "numb": ["12", "34", "56"]
}
```

Expected output where the data in the arrays should be in this format:

```
{
    "first": "abc",
    "last": "rst",
    "numb": "12"
},
{
    "first": "def",
    "last": "uvw",
    "numb": "34"
},
{
    "first": "ghi",
    "last": "xyz",
    "numb": "56"
}
```

Comment: Do you have always three elements and three fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) to "transpose" multiple arrays (as many as you'd like actually):

```
// {
//   first: ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
//   last:  ["rst", "uvw", "xyz"],
//   numb:  ["12", "34", "56"]
// }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $project: { x: { $zip: { inputs: ["$first", "$last", "$numb"] } } } },
  // { x: [["abc", "rst", "12"], ["def", "uvw", "34"], ["ghi", "xyz", "56" ]] }

  { $unwind: "$x" },
  // { x: [ "abc", "rst", "12" ] }
  // { x: [ "def", "uvw", "34" ] }
  // { x: [ "ghi", "xyz", "56" ] }

  { $replaceWith: {
    $arrayToObject: { $zip: { inputs: [["first", "last", "numb"], "$x"] } }
  }} 
])
// { first: "abc", last: "rst", numb: "12" }
// { first: "def", last: "uvw", numb: "34" }
// { first: "ghi", last: "xyz", numb: "56" }
```

This:

- `zip`s the 3 arrays such that elements at the same index will get grouped into the same sub-array.
- `$unwind`s (explodes/flattens) those sub-arrays.
- transforms the resulting arrays into objects to fit your expected output format:

  - by `$zip`ping (again!) the keys we want to associate with the array's values (the keys: `["first", "last", "numb"]` and the values: `"$x"`)
  - and [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) the current document with the result of the `$zip`.

---

Note that prior to Mongo `4.2`, you can use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-replaceRoot) instead of `$replaceWith`.

Comment: nice, i thought about using zip, but then i thought not, you made it concise also, maybe add the ` useLongestLength: <boolean>` and sort, but maybe OP doesn't care of those.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- map on indexes to combine the same index members to 1 document
- keeps the `_id` also to know from which document those came from
  and the index to sort after
- for each index take the element from each array
- unwind
- sort by `_id` and `index` to get the results sorted like it was in the arrays

*indexes are computed using the biggest array, to be safe, in case you already know that all are the same size, you can replace the :
`{"$max":  [{"$size": "$first"}, {"$size": "$last"}, {"$size": "$numb"}]}`
with the size of any  array for example(we need the biggest to work):
`{"$size": "$first"}`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70220158)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
    {"data": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": 
          {"$range": 
            [0,
              {"$max": 
                [{"$size": "$first"}, {"$size": "$last"}, {"$size": "$numb"}]}]},
          "in": 
          {"_id": "$_id",
           "index": "$$this",
           "first": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$first", "$$this"]},
           "last": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$last", "$$this"]},
           "numb": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$numb", "$$this"]}}}}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$data"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$data"}},
  {"$sort": {"_id": 1, "index": 1}},
  {"$unset": ["index"]}])
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/

Comment: @barrypicker i cant guess what you mean with map, but if you can think of better use of map, send us some nicer solution, we learn more things here.